# Create unmanaged c++ object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged dll with a class "MyClass" in it.
Now is there a way to create an instance of this class in C# code? To call its constructor? I tried but the visual studio reports an error with a message that this memory area is corrupted or something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1)
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr p = new IntPtr();
            Program.CreateObserv(ref p);
        }

        [DllImport(@"C:\mm_2008\liba.dll",
            EntryPoint = "??0CRls@fld@@QAE@ABV01@@Z", SetLastError = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
        internal static extern void CreateObserv(ref IntPtr p);
this code throws an AccessViolationException: accessviolationexception attempted to read or write protected memory...

Comment: 2) 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
IntPtr p = Program.CreateObserv();
}

[DllImport(@"C:\mm_2008\liba.dll", EntryPoint = "??0CRls@fld@@QAE@ABV01@@Z", SetLastError = true, allingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
internal static extern IntPtr CreateObserv();

- this code crushes the application and app host

Comment: To avoid mangled entry point names like "??0CRls@fld@@QAE@ABV01@@Z", use extern "C" in unmanaged Dll. Function declared as extern "C" is exported without name mangling.

Comment: @Evgeny007 don't put code in comments, delete your comments and put the code in the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C# cannot create class instance exported from native Dll. You have two options:

1. Create C++/CLI wrapper. This is .NET Class Library which can be added as Reference to any other .NET project. Internally, C++/CLI class works with unmanaged class, linking to native Dll by standard C++ rules. For .NET client, this C++/CLI class looks like .NET class.
2. Write C wrapper for C++ class, which can be used by .NET client with PInvoke. For example, over-simplified C++ class:

```
    class MyClass()
    {
    public:
        MyClass(int n){data=n;}
        ~MyClass(){}
        int GetData(){return data;}
    private:
        int data;
    };
```

C API wrapper for this class:

```
    void* CreateInstance()
    {
        MyClass* p = new MyClass();
        return p;
    }

    void ReleaseInstance(void* pInstance)
    {
        MyClass* p = (MyClass*)pInstance;
        delete p;
    }

    int GetData(void* pInstance)
    {
        MyClass* p = (MyClass*)pInstance;
        return p->GetData();
    }

    // Write wrapper function for every MyClass public method.
    // First parameter of every wrapper function should be class instance.
```

CreateInstance, ReleaseInstance and GetData may be declared in C# client using PInvoke, and called directly. void* parameter should be declared as IntPtr in PInvoke declaration.

Comment: You miss an extern "C" in the wrapper functions.

Comment: Danvil - this is what I wrote in the question note. Anyway, thanks, I really feel better now.

Comment: @Alex What if there is a hierarchy of classes in the native C++ dll...??

Comment: What makes it a "C" API? Aren't `new` and `delete` C++ constructs? Seems like just a static C++ API

Comment: @Rotem: I mean, this wrapper is available for C client, as well as any client working with C-style API: .NET PInvoke, Assembly, Delphi etc. Wrapper itself is implemented in C++.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is create C++/CLI wrapper like:

```
#include "DllExportClass.h"

public ref class ManagedOperationHelper
{
    public:

    double Sum(double add1, double add2)
    {
        CDllExportClass obj;
        double ret=obj.Sum(add1, add2);
        return ret;
    }

    double Mult(double mult1, double mult2)
    {
        CDllExportClass obj;
        double ret=obj.Mult(mult1, mult2);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

where CDllExportClass is the class exported from native code. Above is the .h of the C++/CLI. Take care to let find the lib to this dll. Put the dll and the lib in the same directory and compile the C++/CLI code.In the managed code directory put the native dll and the C++/CLI dll. In the managed project put the reference of the C++/CLI project. Instanciate in the maged code the C++/CLI class like:

```
ManagedOperationHelper obj = new ManagedOperationHelper();
double ret=obj.Sum(10, 20);
```

It's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use unmanged C++ code directly in C#. The interoperability can be done using PInvoke. There are [a lot of issues related to this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-cpp-interop-implicit-pinvoke), especially when calling functions which have pointers as arguments.

The basic procedure goes like this:

**C# part**

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  public class Test {
    [DllImport("TheNameOfThe.dll")]
    public static extern void CreateMyClassInstance();
    
    public void CallIt() {
        CreateMyClassInstance(); // calls the unmanged function via PInvoke
    }
  }
}
```

**C++ part**

```
class MyClass {
  public: MyClass() { /** Constructor */ }
};

MyClass* staticObject;

extern "C" void CreateMyObjectInstance() {
   staticObject = new MyClass(); // constructor is called
}
```

Comment: thanks to everyone, I hated to admit it but looks like there is no other way besides writing a wrapper.

Comment: Other option is to write managed c++ using compiler /crl flag. Then you can mix unmanaged and managed code in same dll and then simple call managed methods in your C# code. It will produce sam IL code as you would wrap native methods in your code. Quick intro http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes

Comment: The link is dead