# How to create an object from an unmanaged dll? 

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I have created a dll containing unmanaged c++ code (not a COM object).

While there are many examples on how to PInvoke the STATIC methods in the dll, I found no way on how to construct an object form a contained class. Is this possible?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636958/create-unmanaged-c-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you Likurg, that post answers the question.